# Why UserManager does not save user to database

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core, identity

I tried to fix that issue by myself and tried many possible ways.

The problem is - when I use `UserManager.CreateAsync(user, request.Password)` and then `_context.SaveChangesAsync()` no records to the table is added. And `_context.SaveChangesAsync()` returns **0**, which means that no record were affected

But after user is created with **CreateAsync**, and then add using this `_context.Users.AddAsync(user)` and call **SaveChangesAsync()**, everything will be saved.

PS. user.Id has value, there is no exceptions on SaveChangesAsync and on CreateAsync, I have tried try-catch those places

Here is code which I am currently using.

**ApplicationDbContext.cs**

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User>, IApplicationDbContext
    {

        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<ExternalApplications> Applications { get; set; }

        public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            return await base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
        }
    }
```

**PersistenceDI.cs**

```
public static class PersistenceDI
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddPersistenceLayer(this IServiceCollection services, string connectionString)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

        services.AddIdentityCore<User>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>().AddUserManager<UserManager<User>>();

        services.AddScoped<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();

        return services;
    }
}
```

**User.cs**

```
public class User : IdentityUser
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
```

**CreateUserCommandHandler.cs**

```
public record CreateuserCommand : IRequest<string>
    {
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }

    public class CreateUserCommandHandler : IRequestHandler<CreateuserCommand, string>
    {
        public IApplicationDbContext _context;
        public UserManager<User> _userManager;

        public CreateUserCommandHandler(IApplicationDbContext context, UserManager<User> userManager)
        {
            _context = context;
            _userManager = userManager;
        }

        public async Task<string> Handle(CreateuserCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            User user = new User
            {
                Email = request.Email,
                FirstName = request.FirstName,
                LastName = request.LastName,
                UserName = request.FirstName + " " + request.LastName + "eqweetwtweywe",
            };

            await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, request.Password);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);

            return user.Id;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix this, error wasn't uncaptured by try catch block.
_userManager.CreateAsync() returns IdentityResult, an when I checked it, there was an error with user name.